# How can I store a variable in Python?

Tags: python, variables

```
def potenza_bruttissima(corpus, msg, initial_key, max_lenght=None, attempts=10, correct_key=""):
    candidate_plaintext= key_application(msg, initial_key)
    if not max_lenght:
        max_lenght=len(candidate_plaintext)

    max_score= text_score(corpus,msg)
    best_key= initial_key
    permutations=math.factorial(len(initial_key))/math.factorial(len(initial_key)-2)
    
    for i in range(attempts):
        print("iter", i)
        p=list(key_swapper(initial_key))
        best_candidate=candidate_plaintext
        perc=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
        for idx, k in enumerate(p):
            advance=int(100*idx/permutations)
            if advance in perc:
                print(f'computed',advance, '% of the permutations')
                print('chiave:', k)
                perc.pop(0)
            candidate_plaintext= key_application(msg, k)
            score= candidatext_score_bigram(corpus, msg)
            
            
            if score>max_score:
                max_score=score
                best_key=k
                best_candidate=candidate_plaintext
                break 
                
    print(f'Candidate key:', best_key)
    print(f'Candidate plaintext:', best_candidate)
```

This code should save as best key the variable k if its score is higher than max_score and break the inner loop.
Then it should use as new best key the variable k in the function key_swapper in the 'outside' loop, but it doesn't.
Instead the code keeps using as best key the starting key, the key instatiated at the beginning.
Why so?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I tried fixing the indentation and formatting, I assume the above is more like what you wanted to post? Can you show an example of how you call this function? It's unclear what you mean by `the variable k in the function key_swapper` - it's clear that you obtain `p` from the results of the call to `key_swapper(initial_key)` and that `k` is looping over those values, and that under some condition `best_key=k`. However, it's unclear what values you're passing into this function `potenza_bruttissima()` and you didn't provide the code for the `key_swapper` function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
def potenza_bruttissima(corpus, msg, initial_key, max_lenght=None, attempts=10, correct_key=""):
    candidate_plaintext= key_application(msg, initial_key)
        max_lenght=len(candidate_plaintext)
    
    max_score= text_score(corpus,msg)
    best_key= initial_key
    permutations=math.factorial(len(initial_key))/math.factorial(len(initial_key)-2)
    
    for i in range(attempts):
        print("iter", i)
        p=list(key_swapper(best_key))
        best_candidate=candidate_plaintext
        perc=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
        for idx, k in enumerate(p):
            advance=int(100*idx/permutations)
            if advance in perc:
                print(f'computed',advance, '% of the permutations')
                print('chiave:', k)
                perc.pop(0)
            candidate_plaintext= key_application(msg, k)
            score= candidatext_score_bigram(corpus, msg)
            
            
            if score>max_score:
                max_score=score
                best_key=k
                best_candidate=candidate_plaintext
                break 
                
    print(f'Candidate key:', best_key)
    print(f'Candidate plaintext:', best_candidate)


def key_swapper(s):
    for i,j in combinations(range(len(s)), 2):
        res = list(s)
        res[i], res[j] = res[j], res[i]
        yield ''.join(res)
```

The given function takes as inputs:

- a corpus text
- a encrypted text
- a starting decryption key
- the number of decryption attempts

The function starts by computing the score of the text decrypted using the starting decryption key and then the key_swapper function takes as an input (best_key) a string and returns all the possible permutation of 2 letters change of that string.

The second loop computes the score of each permutation of the starting key and the first permutation k that scores higher than the initial key become the new best key (the one that should be used in the key_swapper function once we break the second loop).

But broken the second loop the key_swapper function keeps using as best key the starting key, while during the first iteration of the first loop I changed it by assigning k to best_key.

Hope it's clear.
Thanks for any help